# How to represent data graphically in which a respondents can choose more than one group?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, pie-chart

I am analyzing a survey in which one of the questions was (What is the industry segment of your company?) and the respondents can choose more than one category.

I have used a pie chart to represent that data but then I thought this is not very accurate, since one company can choose more than one option. Any suggestion on what can I do to improve the representation?

Comment: Are you just interested in total counts or in comparing respondents?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways how to deal with this:

- The pie/bar chart might consider not original $n$ categories, but all $2^n$ combinations.
- To consider the Carnaugh maps where the color intensity shows the number of answers for given combination of categories.
- Under some conditions, you can use some kind of 2D map where each category has a region (Venn diagram) and you put a marker per record in to the categories (intersections).
- The assigmenent to the categories can be considered as a usual vector and then self-organizing maps can be employed. This will be most likely related to some information loss, but it can cope with complex data approximately.